# MySQL Audit for particular database

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

How to get audit log file for particular database in MySQL. Since databases is in server i am not having any authority for admin permission.But I need Audit Log file.Is there query or method to get all the audit files

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there's no way to retrieve the audit log via sql... however you can find some settings regarding it :

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'audit_log%';
```

You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/audit-log-plugin.html). Bottom line is you need shell access in order to retrieve it.